# I tried to insert values into a table but the unique constraint failed, how do I resolve this?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

[Previous error]

```
line 138, in place_order
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'Order' (OrderNo, CustomerID, Date, TotalCost) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type
```

[Current error]

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'Order' (OrderNo, CustomerID, Date, TotalCost) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: Order.OrderNo, Order.CustomerID
```

I am getting this error but I am not entirely sure what it means, before this error occurred I was getting an error saying that the data types I was trying to insert was 'unsupported'. I think it may be something to do with SQL interpreting Order as a built-in function? This is the code where the error is popping up. (I'm using SQLITE3 btw)

```
buy_another_flag = 2
ordernum = 0
while buy_another_flag != 1:
    option = int(input("Enter the ID of the item you would like to order: "))
    option_quant = int(input("Enter quantity: "))
    now = str(datetime)
    ordernum += 1
    sql_cost = "SELECT UnitPrice FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID=?"
    cursor.execute(sql_cost, [option])
    connection.commit()
    price_for_item = cursor.fetchall()
    total_item_price = str(price_for_item * option_quant)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'Order' (OrderNo, CustomerID, Date, TotalCost) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (
        ordernum, custid_Sorder, now, total_item_price))
    connection.commit()
buy_another_flag = int(input("Would you like to purchase another item?\n1. No\n2. Yes\n> "))
```

This is the table I would like to insert the values into

```
tblorder = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Order"
        (
         OrderNo INT,
         CustomerID INT,
         Date TEXT,
         TotalCost FLOAT,
         primary key(OrderNo, CustomerID)
         foreign key(CustomerID) references Customer(CustomerID)
         )"""

cursor.execute(tblorder)
connection.commit()
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should use `AUTOINCREMENT` for the order number, instead of assigning it in Python.

Comment: The problem is that every time you run this code you start from order number 1, which will duplicate a previous order that you entered for the same customer.

Comment: This isn't the source of the error, but don't use reserved words for table or column names in SQL, it's like naming a function `return()` in Python. If you must use reserved words for table or column names in SQL, enclose them in backticks in queries or use parameter binding to handle it for you.

Comment: @MichaelRuth, learn about parameter binding before giving advices.

Answer (score 0):

In your database schema, you've defined the primary key as a composite of these two columns `orderNo` and `CustomerID`. It means you cannot insert in this table several with the same value in these two columns.

Your error means that you're inserting twice a row with the same `orderNo` and `customerID` value.